# MS Excel Vba/Macro equivalent in LibreCalc or OpenOfficeCalc

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba, libreoffice

is there an equivalent macro/vba in libre calc that does this routine;
- Read/open xls files in a path and do a batch import/copy of read sheets and merge it with the current open workbook.
Here's the vba I used in MS Excel. Thanks in advance

```
Sub Consolidate_Sheets()
'Folder Path to read the xlsx files from

  Path = "F:\WIP2\Below 25\"
  filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

  Do While filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open filename:=Path & filename, ReadOnly:=True

    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets     
     'import/copy sheets from to read xlsx files
      sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    
    Next sheet

    Workbooks(filename).Close
    filename = Dir()
  Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenOffice/LibreOffice has a VBA-like macro system which is designed to have a good degree of compatibility with VBA.

You can get to it by Tools->Macros->Organize Macros->(Libre/Open)Office Basic... If you then click "Edit" you get an editor that is very similar to the VBA IDE.

It's fairly likely that your macro will work with minimal modifications. (Your code seems to run without errors for me, but I obviously don't have your input files.)